# Donoho-Tanner Phase Transition Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create phase-transition plots in Matlab, but don't know how to program the acutal plots. My data is, for example, the following matrix:

```
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.1000    1.0000
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2000    1.0000
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.2000    0.3000    1.0000
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.1000    0.5000    1.0000
     0         0         0    0.1000         0    0.4000    0.3000    0.5000    0.7000    1.0000    0.9000    1.0000
0.6000    0.4000    0.8000    0.9000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
```

For now, what I want to do is basically plot the rows against the columns and represent the entries as shades, for example with 1 being represented as white and 0 being represented as black. The result should look somehting like this:

[image: Phase Transition Plots]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `imshow(matrix)` would work, where `matrix` is the matrix in your example...

Comment: Yes I've also tried it with imshow, but I was wondering if there is a better alternative with more customization options (like colour, axis, proportions), and I also want to add curves to the plot later on

Comment: You can change the colours using `colormap` e.g. `colormap('parula')` (or with your own RGB scale) and use `hold on` to add all the curves you like... These are not limitations of `imshow`. If you can demonstrate what you've tried and why it's not satisfactory then that would help.

Answer (score 0):

use `imagesc`

```
colormap(gray)
imagesc(my_data,[0 1])
```

0 maps to black and 1 maps to white